# Android - Can't hide progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar, visibility

So I've checked the other questions to hide a progress bar but all seem to suggest doing what I'm already doing.

I'm trying to use

```
mProductListProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and I'm finding it by

```
mProductListProgressBar = (ProgressBar) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.product_list_progressbar);
```

I know it's the correct progress bar as I can move it around the screen before with various LayoutParams commands. But it won't hide.

The current code I have (including the moving of the progress bar) is

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
mProductListProgressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
mProductListProgressBar.setLayoutParams(params);

mProductListProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mProductListErrorTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mProductListErrorTextView.setText(errorMessage);
```

The progress bar moves to left and bottom but is still visible. I have tried View.INVISIBLE  as well as View.GONE but neither work.

It's driving me nuts!

Thanks

UPDATE 1

```
protected void showError(int errorMessage){

    /*RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    mProductListProgressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    mProductListProgressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
    */
    mProductListProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mProductListErrorTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mProductListErrorTextView.setText(errorMessage);
}
```

and calling it with

```
showError(R.string.wish_list_empty);
```

UPDATE 2

xml of fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/product_list_gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/standardMargin"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:numColumns="@integer/columns"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/standardMargin" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/product_list_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/refineHeaderHeight"
        android:background="@drawable/product_list_header"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dropdown_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_list_header_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="@dimen/standardTextSize" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_list_refine_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:text="@string/refine"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#838383"
            android:textSize="@dimen/standardTextSize" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/product_list_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/product_list_footer"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_list_footer_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/loading_message"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/standardTextSize" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/product_list_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_list_error_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/standardTextSize"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/debug"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#aa000000"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post up your entire activity class?

Comment: I'm doing this in a fragment. You want both?

This is work code, so I'm not actually sure I'm allowed to paste entire activities etc? I can post the entire function that is called and how it's called too

Comment: Are there other items in relative layout whose position is dependent/"relative" to your `mProductListProgressBar` ?

Comment: xml, want me to post the xml? It's quite big... and no, nothing relates to it

Comment: Just post up the fragment this is called in.The more information you give the easier it will be to help us.

Comment: The majority of the code is in the fragment let me check to see if I'm allowed and if there is anything 'sensitive'

Comment: @Russ In your fragment code, is there any code that sets some element position relative to `mProductListProgressBar`

Comment: @kiruwka ah! It is being used against the gridview on the page using      gridView.setEmptyView(emptyView); (emptyView is being passed in as the progressbar)

Comment: @Russ well, I guess that could explain that it does not make it gone then. Try passing something else. And also check that your `mProductListProgressBar` is not referenced elsewhere, for example some other view position "relative" to your progress bar

Comment: I'm pretty certain that it's not referenced anywhere else. I've grepped through my code for 'product_list_progressbar' and the only place it's used is in this fragment. I think you might be onto something though with the emptyView thing. I have no idea what that's used for (this is all inherited code) but it's at least something to look for

Comment: First try passing `null` to setEmptyView(); and see if that solves it as a quick hack. also grep for `mProductListProgressBar` in your file to be super sure.

Comment: @Russ `setEmptyView` sets the view to show something when your adapter is empty. Try setting it to null, or some dummy `new View()`;

Comment: @kiruwka Yehaaaa! That's hidden it! Now, I have to work out whether that will screw things up by setting it to null. I don't even know why it's used. Actually, on quick tests everything appears to be working...can you somehow write an answer with all those bits/comments in and i'll accept it

Comment: @Russ Yes, I will do it, give me a sec.

Comment: Please check the answer and let me know if you need more info. And don't recommend setting setEmtpyView to null, as I expect that may give NPE when you don't have items to display(not sure if it will though, but I will check).

Comment: @kiruwka well it appears to work. It's set every time the fragment is loaded/created anyway, I'm only setting it to null in this instance when the list is empty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43128/discussion-between-kiruwka-and-russ-wheeler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this behaviour usually happens when your view which you try to hide is needed / referenced by someone else.

In your case, as you mentioned in the comments, you use `mProductListProgressBar` for `setEmptyView()` of your `GridView`.

Another possibility of running into similar troubles when there other views in your relative container layout which set their position *relatively* to your `mProductListProgressBar`. This setting could be either in the code or in .xml.

Please make sure you don't have any of above and View.GONE should work fine.

As for [setEmptyView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29) - it is only used to show something meaningful to the user when your adapter is empty. I recommend just setting up simple Layout for that with, say, `TextView "no items"`, in the middle, and pass it to `setEmptyView()`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, it turns out you can simply set `setEmptyView(null)` which I guess is equivalent to ignoring this call altogether. I just tried it, in case of no data you will have blank gridview.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it is an old question. But I just spent a lot of time debugging similar situation. I could not hide ProgressBar on top of unityPlayer view.

One more thing to ensure is that You are hiding it while in UI thread.

To ensure surround Your UI code with:

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that worked for me was to hide the view in XML:

`android:visibility="gone"`

and then unhide/hide it at runtime when needed:

`yourProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) // or View.VISIBLE depending on situation`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your code is written but had similar problem and resolved by removing the view object from declaration

like

```
mProductListProgressBar = (ProgressBar) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.product_list_progressbar);
```

should be

```
mProductListProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.product_list_progressbar);
```

Try it and check

Reason is the progress bar is on the top of every view in the hierarchy and it's not belong to any root view.

Comment: if I remove mRoot it says 'The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type ProductListFragment' I'm doing all this in a fragment. Also, it's not like the progress bar isn't being found by that line as I am able to move it about the screen, just not hide it

Comment: use getListView().FindViewById(int)

Comment: getListView didn't work (not a valid/recognised function) so I used getView, but this didn't hide the progressbar anyway. As I said it was already grabbing the progress bar successfully anyway. I think @kiruwka has come up with something, in that it is tied to the gridview