# Can't remove or hide a view in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-progressbar

I'm trying to remove a progress indicator after loading my data in a fragment involving a ListView. Here is my completion handler:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        dataSource = (ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) task.getResult();
        PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), dataSource);
        ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        View indicator = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layout.removeView(indicator);
    }
});
```

The last 3 lines of code is the relevant part. Everything is called correctly, nothing is null etc. in debug everything works perfectly. The adapter also works correctly, populating my list, but the indicator is still on the screen. I've also tried setting it's visibility to `GONE` or `HIDDEN` but they also don't seem to hide it either. I've seen [Android - Can't hide progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565250/android-cant-hide-progress-bar) but it's answers involve `setEmptyView()` which I'm not using anyway. I am using the same fragment (of course, a different instance) in another tab, and it works correctly.

Here is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, so, you a displaying a progress bar to publish the progress being done, correct? and you want to hide it but you cannot. Am I getting it right? (:

Comment: I had faced this issue. Did you have same name "R.id.indicator" for different fragment ? If yes , can you try to rename different name for other "R.id.indicator" ?  Please share result.

Comment: @LittleChild yes, exactly.

Comment: @Rollno1 I've searched the whole project. There is no other resource called `indicator` anywhere.

Comment: Could you add your layout.xml to your question? Maybe it will help.

Comment: @Rollno1 by the way, I am reusing another instance of the same fragment at somewhere else, and there, it disappears correctly.

Comment: Check if you don't have any other R.id.layout in layouts.
Also try to do 

View indicator = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.indicator);

((ViewGroup)indicator.getParent()).removeView(indicator);

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu: Have you checked that the view that you are seeing is available on different fragment with different name ? In fragment layout xml, have you put background color ? it my case , my fragment has transparent background and old view is not covered which ends that view despite i moved to new screen.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out the problem (thanks to all the commenters). I was calling activity's methods to find and remove the view. The problem is that, I have multiple instances of the same fragment in the same activity, under different tabs. I've used my fragment's root view to find and remove the indicator, instead of the activity, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Change the codes of last three lines in `onClick(...)` as:

```
View indicator = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
```

and use:

```
indicator.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
```

or codes:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.removeView(indicator);
```

Comment: I did not see you have answered yourself with the same solution.