# How to stop the progress bar after getting response from the server

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar

I'm trying to stop the progress bar after getting response from server.
Below is the xml code that I've used

`activity.xml`

```
  <ProgressBar
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

`activity.kt`

```
 var progressBar =  findViewById(R.id.progressBar) as ProgressBar
 doAsync {
            try {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    appList = getAppList(requestBody, LAUNCHER_BASE_URL)
                    Log.d("App list =", appList.toString())
                    appInfoList = populateList()
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.e("Exception-launcher", e.toString())
            }
```

From the above code,progress bar is not stopping even after getting the response. Any help would be appreciated

I've tried that but the page becomes blank after the progress bar stops

Comment: Because your progress bar is gone while it throw some exception not that time when you get success response.

Comment: so you wanted to show the response to user after progressbar stop ? and Your display becomes blank after progress bar gone. It means you didn't attached your response to your design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Can't hide progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565250/android-cant-hide-progress-bar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` in your try clause too, because in its current state, it will only remove the loading for when the API fails:

```
 var progressBar =  findViewById(R.id.progressBar) as ProgressBar
 doAsync {
            try {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    appList = getAppList(requestBody, LAUNCHER_BASE_URL)
                    Log.d("App list =", appList.toString())
                    appInfoList = populateList()
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.e("Exception-launcher", e.toString())
            }
```

Comment: i've tried and the progress bar stops but the issue is that the screen becomes blank after the progress bar had gone

Comment: I'm not sure how layout is laid out, but try `View.INVISIBLE` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thank you so much,it is working .Instead of `View.GONE` .I've used `View.INVISIBLE`

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
doAsync {
    try {
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        appList = getAppList(requestBody, LAUNCHER_BASE_URL)
        Log.d("App list =", appList.toString())
        appInfoList = populateList()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        Log.e("Exception-launcher", e.toString())
    } finally {
        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    }
```

Comment: i've tried and the progress bar stops but the issue is that the screen becomes blank after the progress bar had gone

Comment: i guess the problem is in your xml

Comment: there is no issue in xml too that you attached in above

Comment: i guess its your view composition that creating issue, you should try `View.INVISIBLE` instead of `View.GONE`

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the progressbar only if the code goes in `Exception` (catch block).

Move your code after the catch block, as follows:

```
    try {
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         appList = getAppList(requestBody, LAUNCHER_BASE_URL)
         Log.d("App list =", appList.toString())
         appInfoList = populateList()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
         Log.e("Exception-launcher", e.toString())
    }
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: i've tried and the progress bar stops but the issue is that the screen becomes blank after the progress bar had gone

Comment: @ChristinaVarghese can you please add your XML code?

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918219/how-to-disable-user-interaction-while-progressbar-is-visible-in-android?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear how can you handle `View` inside `doAsync`
Normally this should represents in this way

```
 val progressBar =  findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar)
 progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
 doAsync {
      try {
         appList = getAppList(requestBody, LAUNCHER_BASE_URL)
         Log.d("App list =", appList.toString())
         appInfoList = populateList()              
      } catch (e: Exception) {
          e.printStackTrace()
      }

      uiThread {
         progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
      }
 }
```